# A version of DebugBreak that breaks the debugger without crashing the app

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way to do something like [DebugBreak()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugbreak) where when that function is hit the debugger breaks, but continue running when no debugger is attached?

I have a lua error handler that presents a user-friendly error message when something goes wrong, but if I'm debugging I want to stop execution as soon as I've detected something wrong.

I don't want to set a breakpoint in the debugger UI. I want a line of code that causes the debugger to break so I can share this breakpoint with co-workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`IsDebuggerPresent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-isdebuggerpresent) to check for an attached debugger, and then conditionally invoke `DebugBreak`:

```
if (IsDebuggerPresent()) {
    DebugBreak();
}
```

Comment: For porting, I found an [implementation of IsDebuggerPresent for macOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1361/_index.html).